# Jquery Ajax jsonp request display in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please excuse this question but I cant quite get my head around what I am doing wrong, I am trying to make a jsonp request via ajax and jquery - if i look at the response my data shows fine, however I cant get my head around how to display it in the console.

here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var jsondata = [];
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '<myurl with json response in a form of an array >?callback=?', 
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

just to clarify my response shows like this:

```
[{"content":asdf,"created_at":"date","asdf":"asdf"}]
```

Comment: you should be seeing an array in your console with what you are currently using. If you aren't, then your url isn't returning jsonp.

Comment: `[{"content":asdf,"created_at":"date","asdf":"asdf"}]` isn't valid JSON and it isn't valid JSONP.

Comment: thanks Kevin its coming from a response from a rails app is there a way I can parse it to jsonp or do I need to do the from the rails server?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an ARRAY of objects, so reference the array index, followed by property:

```
console.log(data[0].content);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var content = data.content;
 var created_at= data.created_at;
 var asdf= data.asdf;

console.log(content);
console.log(created_at);
console.log(asdf);
```

Try this

Comment: given output is not valid jsonp.. it works fine with json.
i have used above solution using   **contentType: 'application/json',dataType: "json"**

Comment: No, the problem is that the given output is an array of objects. With quotes around that one value, it would be valid, but your code would still be undefined. However, it's important to note that at the moment, the OP isn't even getting to the console. contentType: 'application/json' is wrong for the data currently being sent (and is ignored for jsonp requests anyway)

Comment: So just to confirm if my JSON isnt valid from source I cannot pull it in with ajax?

Comment: that is correct. if the source isn't returning JSON + cors headers or JSONP you can't get it with ajax (i'm assuming it's cross-domain at this point)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sgbangale/J5cEX/
This is working
i think json should be of this format(in above jsfiddle)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I have access the other server so I will convert it into valid JSON.